# Dual boot loading windows boot manager

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have SSD and HDD on my computer, I installed ubuntu along side Windows 10 on the SSD, but when i turn on my computer Windows 10 was loaded without GRUB showing. I followed the order in this video:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=F4fPwUFTwlk
and now Windows Boot Manager is loaded, but the only option is load Windows 10.
How can I make the GRUB menu appear?

[This is the boot options in my bios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbioK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the boot order in bios settings. Make Ubuntu boot first in os boot manager as for hp machines, then it will show GRUB menu.

Comment: After restarting and entering in BIOS Setup, there is an option of boot manager in boot configuration option in my hp pavilion.

Comment: I meant that the 'ubuntu' option isn't there. I edited and added picture of my boot options.

Comment: you have to select os boot manager and then change the boot order by pressing f6.

Comment: press f10 after placing it first

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your PC and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd>,<kbd>F1</kbd> to boot loder. ([As you mentioned its HP Lap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969825/dual-boot-loading-windows-boot-manager/969837#comment1553378_969827))

Once you got the boot setting, Set ubuntu as default.

> As know <kbd>Esc</kbd> will set temporary session for boot. Means if you load it again it will load windows.